# delete duplicate by considering specific criteria

Tags: duplicates, ms-access-2010, criteria, sql-delete, specifications

I would like to ask you to remove duplicates but remain the specific one.

[image: SerWorkNumber is du]

if there is a "FD" in the type the code should not deleted it.

[image]

I would be very apprecated for any help. I stucked in :(
Thank you

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Thank you @Tim Biegeleisen. ı used Msaccess

Comment: The code I wrote is

>DELETE CD_FD.[SerWorkNumber], CD_FD.[SerialNo], CD_FD.[ServiceCenter], CD_FD.[ReceivedDate], CD_FD.[Type]
FROM CD_FD
WHERE (((CD_FD.[SerWorkNumber]) In (SELECT [SerWorkNumber] FROM [CD_FD] As Tmp GROUP BY [SerWorkNumber] HAVING Count(*)>1 )) AND ((CD_FD.[Type])="CD"));

Comment: Dear @Tim Biegeleisen do you have a solution for this. I would be very appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do this, is to have a unique identifier on every row. so if you don't already have one, create a new column called "row_id" and set it to AutoNumber. save the table, you should now have a unique id on every row.

Next, you can construct a big ugly sql to do what you need, but if your table is large, it won't perform well with sub-queries. so its probably best to use a temporary table to save the duplicate rows, and then reference it for your delete statement.

so first identify the duplicates, and store the min row id.

```
SELECT a.SerWorkNumber, a.SerialNo, a.Type, Min(a.row_id) AS MinOfrow_id INTO CD_FD_Dups
FROM CD_FD AS a
GROUP BY a.SerWorkNumber, a.SerialNo, a.Type
HAVING count(1) > 1;
```

next, delete from the actual table referencing the temp table you created above:

```
DELETE 
FROM CD_FD AS a
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1
 FROM CD_FD_Dups d
 WHERE d.SerWorkNumber = a.SerWorkNumber
      and  d.SerialNo = a.SerialNo
      and   d.Type = a.Type
      and   a.row_id > d.MinOfrow_id
);
```